# deploying local WAR in test environment without teamcity

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, teamcity, war

I have a JAVA application that is built using Maven with Spring and Hibernate . My project uses TeamCity to generate the new WAR whenever any code change is commited into SVN.I need to find an alternative to using teamcity. i.e. , we need to be able to deploy the local WAR into the test environment(so that Testers can do their job) without help of teamCity. I have tried replacing the TeamCity WAR with the local WAR , but that is not working . Any suggestions would be welcome .

Comment: Exactly what's the problem? Do you have problem packaging the WAR outside of Teamcity? Does it not work when you deploy it to the application server? Please be more specific and include any possible exception/error logs to your question. And you don't specify which application server you are using.

Comment: What application server do you use? Tomcat, WebSphere, WebLogic?

Comment: I am using Tomcat ..It does not work when I deloy my WAR to Tomcat in Test env(that was working till now with the Teamcity WAR)..The same WAR works in my local machine ..Do I need to make any config changes to the WAR ?

Comment: is there any error message?

Comment: Is there any specific cause for you to avoid TeamCity?

Comment: Maybe when building war file locally, it packaged different configuration files than building it from Teamcity. Do you use exactly same "command" to build the war file locally as in Teamcity?